# How to use console command to quit infinite loop in C#

Tags: c#, console

So I have an infinite loop that runs some code and I want it to run forever until a user types an exit command. However the problem I am having is when the code reaches the ReadLine command, it stays there until it receives a valid input from the console. How can I code it so it will move on to the rest of the code and only read from the console if there is a valid input

```
while(true)
{
  uint quit = Uint32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  if(quit == 1){
  break;
   }    
  else{
//some other code 
} 
}
```

Comment: Is the [Console.KeyAvailable Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable) (with example) what you're looking for?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes this is perfect thank you!, I assumed there was a built in property to check this but wasn't sure the exact name of it

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to look into [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming).

Essentially, you're going to want to create a `Task` that takes care of running your code in the background, and you can wait for some console input to cancel the task if needed.

Typically this is achieved by implementing a [Cancellation Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation), which you can update from your loop that is waiting for user input.

Here is an example app I just made that should show you how this is accomplished:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // create our token source here
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // and get the actual cancellation token from the token source
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            // have the Task library run an async task for us, and pass in our cancellation Token
            Task.Run(
                
                async () => {

                // while our task is not cancelled
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // perform our code
                    Console.WriteLine("Simulated background code.");
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }


            }, cancellationToken);

            // say hi
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");


            // while we havent requested a cancellation we loop
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // wait on reading a line
                var escape = Console.ReadLine();

                // if that line is quit we cancel the token
                if (escape == "quit")
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("See you later.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an Asynchronous library which monitors the console for keystrokes and will pipe out commands.

I would recommend becoming familiar with [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8)

The pattern usually is to implement some form of `IAsyncEnumerable<YourApplicationEvent>` service.

Whenever you need to pipe out to the console you can have the async service `yield return` a `YourApplicationEvent`, while also piping out a `YourApplicationEvent` whenever the user hits enter to send command.

I use a method like this usually for this type of task:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ConsoleEvents([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken token)
{
    await using var reader = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    var commandBuffer = new List<byte>();
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        var readCount = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, token);
        var command = new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer, 0, readCount));

        yield return command.TrimEnd();
    }
}
```